# Cannot mount local directory into container from docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to mount the local directory of a project to docker container before I used COPY command but when I make changes I have to rebuild those parts which involve some installation from bash scripts.

This is my `docker-compose` file

```
version "3.7"
services
 tesseract:
    container_name: tesseract
    build:
      context: ./app/services/tesseract/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/services/tesseract:/tesseract/
```

I don't have any errors when building and my `WORKDIR tesseract` is empty when i run container

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TESSERACT=/usr/share/tesseract

WORKDIR /tesseract

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    python3.7 \
    python3-pip \
    cmake \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool \
    pkg-config \
    libpng-dev \
    tesseract-ocr \
    libtesseract-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libjpeg8-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    wget \
    git \
    g++ \
    vim

RUN git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract $TESSERACT

COPY . /tesseract/
RUN chmod +x scripts/*
RUN scripts/compile_tesseract.sh
RUN scripts/langdata_lstm.sh scripts/start.sh
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENV TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract/tessdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Main objective of docker volume is

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

which means volumes are used to persist the data outside the lifecycle of a container. If you want to `COPY` a file or a directory into a container, please use `COPY` instruction.

> If you’re copying in local files to your Docker image, always use `COPY` because it’s more explicit.

With Docker-compose, you can use a bind mount volume

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i didn't like the thing when i make changes inside service directory it rebuilds that part of the container and it involves installing dependencies

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile? Maybe we can do some optimizations in that.

Comment: by the way, i found out from getting started guide that you can mount local directory so you don't need o rebuild container from here https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount   Edited my question

Comment: With docker-compose, you can use a `bind mount` option.
Regarding Docker file, ideally, you should install your dependencies in the initial stage of the image and then copy the rest of the code.

```
COPY requirements.txt /tesseract/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /tesseract/
```
This will save a lot of time while building the image as it will pick up the dependencies from the cache layer

Comment: Can you please check the answer and accept it if it solves the answer?